# Why does the CakePHP Authorization Componentent automatically logout when opening two sites in parallel?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, authorization

I have a problem within my CakePHP application: I use the Authorization Component for the login/logout mechanisms. Unfortunately users are logged out automatically when they try to open two or more php pages at the same moment. Thats happening very often because we tend to use the middle mouse button to open many tabs in short intervals.

Has anybody an idea? Could it be CakePHP or is there a php setting for allowing useres to make multiple requests at the same time?

georg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of session_regenerate_id(). For every page you open, you get a new session_id. This prevent session hijacking (which is uncommon but possible). Turn your security level in config.php down to medium to prevent this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, fixed a problem I had with multiple quick form submissions (i.e. hitting return twice) logging the user out.

Answer (score 1):

you might also have two sites with the same seed  look in your config.php and see if you have unique values in

```
Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'I_like_to_make_this_unique');
Configure::write('Security.salt', 'this_should_be_unique');
```

might help